# How its better to work with Redux useSelector in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new in React Hooks and I'm wonder how its better to do some things. Example the state how its better to keep the state in parent and to pass to the child or to put the state in every component where I need the state? Witch is the good option?

Comment: Do you need example to get clear view? or just an opinion?

Comment: just an opinion

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you use some state values in only one component, you can make it the state of that specific component, making it self-contained.

If a state is used in a component and some of its child components, it's a good idea to store it as a state in the component and pass it as props to child components.

If a state is used in multiple (relatively unrelated) components in an app, you can store it as a global state (through redux or context API) and use it in those components.

Comment: Accesing the state to much time affects somehow the performance? or are some dissavantages? I generally use useSelector in every component where I need. I don t pass it like props

Comment: no performance issue, because that's how React was designed. useSelector is for accessing redux state. props are a big part of React, so you should pass it to child components if necessary.